# Scrapy: grabbing sibling elements of a regex match

Tags: css, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to scrape college essay topics from college websites. I know how to match a keyword using a regular expression, but the information that I really want is the other elements in the same div as the match. The Response.css(...).re(...) function in Scrapy returns a string. Is there any way to navigate to the parent div of the regex match?

Example: https://admissions.utexas.edu/apply/freshman-admission#fndtn-freshman-admission-essay-topics. On the above page, I can match the essay topics h1 using: response.css("*::text").re("Essay Topics"). However, I can't figure out a way to grab the 2 actual essay topics in the same div under Topic A and Topic N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it. You should use something like below

```
response.xpath("//div[@id='freshman-admission-essay-topics']//h5//text()").extract()
```

In case you just want css then you can use

```
In [7]: response.css("#freshman-admission-essay-topics h5::text, #freshman-admission-essay-topics h5 span::text").extract()
Out[7]: ['Topic A \xa0\xa0', 'Topic N']
```

Comment: Thanks for your point. I understand the way you laid out, but I was hoping for a more generalizable parsing approach so I could scrape multiple sites using the same scheme. Is there no way to do something like soup.find_all(href=re.compile("elsie"))
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>] in beautiful soup where you get the tag instead of the string match?

Comment: How can it be generic and extract something specific at the same time?

Comment: Let’s say I want to extract all Li’s in the same div as the regex “Essay Topics”. I could do that if re.compile didn’t return a string but the html element itself. Is there no way to do that?

Comment: You will still need to use xpath as such. Something like `response.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Essay Topics')]/..//text()").extract()`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Would I be able to do this in CSS as well since that's what I'm more comfortable with?

Comment: No. CSS has limitation that it doesn't allow parent traversal

Comment: Thanks Tarun! I appreciate your help and insight.